# Is it possible to page through a view in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Running phpmyadmin version 3.4.8.

I just noticed that there are no "paging" buttons when displaying a view that allows you to jump to the next page or the last page like when browsing a table.

I know you can set `$cfg['MaxRows']` and I tried putting a "ShowAll" button on the page with `$cfg['ShowAll'] = TRUE`. I also know I can fill out the input boxes to the right of the "Show" button.

Phpmyadmin offers so many helpful features I am a little surprised I can't do this, but I haven't used it that long so maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

I think $cfg['MaxExactCountViews'] is the variable you are looking for: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxExactCountViews

Comment: Not very clear in the first, but I tried and it worked. Thank you