# phpMyAdmin is missing pagination button in MySQL views

Tags: phpmyadmin, pagination, view

My phpMyAdmin is missing pagination buttons when showing a view. My view have about 20.000 rows.

How I can enable pagination buttons on views?

Answer (score 7):

Essentially I have to enable row counting for views, by adding this line at the botton of the file config.inc.php (placed in the phpMyAdmin install directory):

```
$cfg['MaxExactCountViews'] = 100000;
```

100000 is the maximum number of rows that you estimate the view will contain. This parameter is defaulted to zero, probably because the row counting impacts on performance.
[Is it possible to page through a view in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822324/is-it-possible-to-page-through-a-view-in-phpmyadmin)

Found the answer here (the answer was not clear to mein the first, but I tried and I worked): [Is it possible to page through a view in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822324/is-it-possible-to-page-through-a-view-in-phpmyadmin)